# How to add a unique randomly generated 6 digit key stored in a model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-models

I need each model in my database to have a unique six-digit key associated with it. For example,

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    randomly_generated_id=models.RandomField() #how do I generate a random key here?
```

Comment: Do you want to generate a random field or a random key value for a specific field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `models.CharField()` and bind the default to a random generator.

```
import random
import string

def key_generator():
    key = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(6))
    if Quiz.objects.filter(randomly_generate_id=key).exists():
        key = key_generator()
    return key

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    randomly_generated_id = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=key_generator, unique=True, editable=False)
```

However, unless you have some specific reason to generate a 6 digits key, I would rather recommend to use an universal identifier using [`models.UUIDField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield). This will especially avoid the overhead of checking that the randomly generated key is not already used.

```
import uuid

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    randomly_generated_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Comment: Alternatively, do they really need to be random, or just unique?  Start at 100000 and increment by 1.